# Proving Quick Sort algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, sorting

Can we provide a proof for the correctness of the following quick sort algorithm:

quicksort(a1,a2,...an) {

(b) less := the empty list
(c) greater := the empty list

pivot = a1

for i := 2 to n

if ai < a1,
adjoin ai to the list "less"

else
adjoin ai to the list "greater"

(m = length(less) and k = length(greater))

if m /= 0, 
then quicksort (b1,b2...bm)

if k /= 0,
then quicksort (c1,c2,..ck)

to put the sorted lists back into a

for i := 1 to m

ai = bi

am+1 = pivot

for i := 1 to k

am+i+1 = ci
}

Comment: Note that the actual Quicksort does the rearranging in place before it is recursively called.